# How to use CTest to check difference between two files?

Tags: testing, cmake, integration-testing, ctest

I'm trying to create some integrated tests for some legacy software. The current way to do testing is to run the code with known inputs and *manually* compare the output to the known output.

I'd like to automate this process, since I'm already using CMake I would like to do this with CTest. I have about two dozen inputs/outputs that I need to check.

**What is the right way to do this?** I only have a moderate amount of experience with CMake and even less with CTest.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/prop_test/PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION.html) property of tests to achieve this.

Say you have code which takes an input of a single int and outputs the phrase "The result is " with 10*input appended.  So e.g. in C++ something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  if (argc != 2)
    return -1;
  std::cout << "The result is " << 10 * std::atoi(argv[1]) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Then you could test for this using CTest by doing:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(Example)

add_executable(example main.cpp)

include(CTest)

set(Inputs 1 2 3)
foreach(Input ${Inputs})
  add_test(NAME Test${Input} COMMAND example ${Input})
  set_tests_properties(Test${Input} PROPERTIES
                       PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION "The result is ${Input}0")
endforeach()
```